# Поиск вводя данные, django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

есть модель:

```
class StarusC(models.Model):
    serialNumber = models.ForeignKey(Catrige, verbose_name='Серийный номер', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    catrigeStatus = models.ForeignKey(StatusCatrige, verbose_name='Статус картриджа', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateChange = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статус картриджа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статусы картриджей'
```

Необходимо производить поиск по `serialNumber`, но так как `serialNumber` является `ForeignKey` можно только выбирать из выпадающего списка.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли данное поле сделать как `TextBox`? И производить поиск вводя данные? Или возможно я не верно спроектировал модель?

Answer (score 1):

В админ класс модели Catrige нужно добавить поиск, например, по имени:

```
@admin.register(Catrige)
class CatrigeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # тут ваш код
    search_fields = ('name',) # вместо "name" - поле, по которому будем искать
    # Можно так же указать другие поля через запятую, например:
    # search_fields = ('id', 'name')
    # тогда поиск будет производиться либо по номеру в БД, либо по имени.
```

Затем в админ класс где будем вместо выпадающего списка давать такой же список с поиском:

```
@admin.register(StarusC)
class StarusCAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ('serialNumber',)
```